# Максимальное и минимальное значение в SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, запрос

Есть таблица из которой нужно вытащить максимальное число (3-я колонка) отсортировавши при этом по 1 и 2 колонке. То есть 1 и 2 колонка задается (таких записей может быть много) но нужна именно так в которой число в 3-й колонке максимальное или минимальное.

```
    cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME_WEATHER, new String[]{CELSIUS, FAHRENHEIT},
            MONTH + " = ?" + " AND " + DAYOFMONTH + " = ?" + " AND " + CELSIUS + " = MAX(" + CELSIUS + ")",
            new String[]{month, date}, null, null, null);
```

Но по этой выборке выскакивает ошибка

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: misuse of aggregate function MAX() (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT celsius, fahrenheit FROM weatherTable WHERE month = ? AND dayofmonth = ? AND celsius = MAX(celsius)
```

Answer (score 1):

В SQLite агрегатные функции (`MAX()`, `SUM()`, `COUNT()` etc) не очень дружат с `WHERE`. Поэтому или так:

```
SELECT celsius, fahrenheit FROM weatherTable 
  HAVING 
month = ? AND dayofmonth = ? AND celsius = MAX(celsius)
```

Или так:

```
SELECT celsius, fahrenheit FROM weatherTable 
  WHERE 
month = ? AND dayofmonth = ? AND celsius IN 
  (SELECT MAX(celsius) FROM weatherTable)
```

Comment: Попробовал второй вариант. Ошибки нет, но ни одного варианта максимума не находит, а вот минимум нашло.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
select 
   max(celsius) as max_celsius, min(celsius) as min_celsius,
   max(fahrenheit) as max_fahrenheit, min(fahrenheit) as min_fahrenheit
from weatherTable 
where 
   month = ? AND dayofmonth = ?`
```

и тогда так:

```
cursor = database.rawQuery(
    "select \n"+
    "  max("+CELSIUS+") as max_"+CELSIUS+", min("+CELSIUS+") as min_"+CELSIUS+",\n"+
    "  max("+FAHRENHEIT+") as max_"+FAHRENHEIT+", min("+FAHRENHEIT+") as min_"+FAHRENHEIT+"\n"+
    "from "+TABLE_NAME_WEATHER+"\n"+
    "where "+MONTH+" = ? AND "+DAYOFMONTH+" = ?", 
    new String[]{month, date});
```

ЗЫ зачем нужны и цельсии и фаренгейты? F=C*9/5+32?